# suspend works but only for a second before exiting back to the desktop

Tags: suspend, power-management, gnome-power-manager

Suspend works but only for a second before exiting back to the desktop.  I'm using an HP ZBook 15 G2 with Ubuntu 18.04.2 installed.  Ubuntu is installed on a SSD partition while the swap disk is on a hard disk.

Before reinstalling 18.04.2 I was using 19.04, suspend was working fine on this install up until a few weeks ago, but stopped for some reason, I would guess possibly a software update.

[Edit]  Not sure if this is anything to do with it, `nouveau` firmware fails to load:

```
# dmesg | grep -i nouveau
[    7.574383] fb: switching to nouveaufb from VESA VGA
[    7.574634] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: NVIDIA GK106 (0e63c0a1)
[    7.619662] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: version 80.06.88.00.07
[    7.620802] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: mxm: BIOS version 3.0
[    7.629105] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: 2048 MiB GDDR5
[    7.715043] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: VRAM: 2048 MiB
[    7.715044] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: GART: 1048576 MiB
[    7.715047] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: TMDS table version 2.0
[    7.715048] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB version 4.0
[    7.715049] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 03: 01075fd6 0f420020
[    7.715051] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 04: 01075f92 00020020
[    7.715052] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 05: 08014fc6 0f420010
[    7.715053] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 06: 08014f82 00020010
[    7.715054] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 08: 04038fb6 0f420010
[    7.715055] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 09: 04038f72 00020010
[    7.715056] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 10: 02027fa6 0f420014
[    7.715058] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 13: 02049f00 00000000
[    7.715129] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 04: 01000446
[    7.715130] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 05: 02000546
[    7.715131] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 06: 00010647
[    7.715132] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 07: 00010747
[    7.715133] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 08: 00020846
[    7.715134] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 09: 00000900
[    7.779433] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: MM: using COPY for buffer copies
[    8.253146] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: allocated 3200x1800 fb: 0xa0000, bo 00000000a027f924
[    8.253303] fbcon: nouveaufb (fb0) is primary device
[    8.253470] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb0: nouveaufb frame buffer device
[    8.268043] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[ 1928.560944] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nve6_fuc084 failed with error -2
[ 1928.560953] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nve6_fuc084d failed with error -2
[ 1928.560956] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: unable to load firmware data
[ 1928.560960] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: init failed, -19
[ 1991.197529] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: devinit: 0x00006d15[0]: script needs OR link
[ 2411.303642] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: devinit: 0x00006d15[0]: script needs OR link
[ 2694.486661] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nve6_fuc084 failed with error -2
[ 2694.486667] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nve6_fuc084d failed with error -2
[ 2694.486668] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: unable to load firmware data
[ 2694.486671] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: init failed, -19
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this with a combination of this post https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Suspend-resume-problems-on-Ubuntu-18-04/td-p/6072410 and this post https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2395562 - installing proprietary NVidia drivers and disabling `nouveau`:

```
# ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

and then adding `nouveau.modeset=0` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub` (running `update-grub`).

Comment: Installing the Nvidia drivers should have been enough.